# Virtual Box Windows xp resolution issue

Tags: virtualbox, display, display-resolution

I use ubuntu 15.04 with my lenovo g505s laptop. I installed virtual box to use windows xp sp3 but there is no 1366x768 resolution. I have already assigned 256mb video memory(instead of 128) but I still cant change the resolution. I have higher resolution options like 1280x1024 but I have to scroll a lot and it makes program using impossible.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install guest additions.

Start a virtual machine, go to "Devices" menu and select "Install guest additions".

[image]

Windows video driver will be installed.

You will be able to set custom resolutions by resizing VM window by your mouse.

Comment: *+1*. The menu is slightly confusing, as there are only a few options to select (start menu + Direct3D for me), which also seem irrelevant here. However, it will install a lot of guest additions on top of them. Following this advice did not only allow me to choose more resolutions, but also sped up my mouse cursor considerably.